# How to delete multiple rows in the radgrid based on the checkbox checked

Tags: gridview, telerik, radgrid, delete-row

I have a radgrid  where item is being binded from codebehind ,how can delete specific rows in the grid based on the checkbox checked , and save the changes to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind checkbox like:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>     
      <ItemTemplate>     
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idKnowledgeArea") %>' />   
      </ItemTemplate>      
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

You have to bind ID to checkbox value. After this when you click delete button then you will get checked checkboxes by :

```
Request.Form["chkBox"].Replace("'", String.Empty)
```

So you will get checked checkboxes IDs. After that you will write your delete code and then you just write code for grid rebind as:

```
Grid.Rebind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , can you be more clear on deleting the row items based on the checkbox checked

Comment: what are you trying to say? can you explain in detail?

Comment: See i have some 20 rows in my grid , and i have a checkbox at the end of each row , if user selects particular checkbox and clicks delete button ,that particular row has to be deleted

Comment: See i have some 20 rows in my grid , and i have a checkbox at the end of each row , if user selects particular checkbox and clicks delete button ,that particular row has to be deleted

Comment: means every row has delete button or you have only one common delete button ?

Comment: I will have one common delete button

Comment: You will get checked checkboxes value by Request.Form["chkBox"].Replace("'", String.Empty).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3163/discussion-between-mahesh-and-parth-patel)